# Помогите объяснить постановку запятой

Tags: запятые, ссп, дополнение

*Компьютер — это устройство для обработки информации. У компьютера нет интеллекта как такового(,) и он называется аппаратом.*

Меня интересует второе предложение, а именно первая его часть. Что это? Одно большое дополнение? *Word* информирует, что пропущена запятая после *как такового*, т.е. перед сочинительным союзом. Но найти основы в первой части предложение я не могу.

Comment: Наверное, все мои проблемы из-за корявости предложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У компьютера нет интеллекта ***как такового***, и он называется аппаратом.

Предложение безличное (отрицательно-бытийное), ***нет*** ― сказуемое. Субъект имеет форму Р.п. и является дополнением.

**Как такового** ― это значит в обычном понимании этого слова, безотносительно к чему-либо. Это обстоятельственное определение к слову ***компьютер***

Из словаря: **Как таковой** ― (мест.) **Самостоятельный, целый** (безотносительно к чему-либо иному). Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Примеры:

Причём сценария **как такового** у них не было ― они предложили заняться им мне. [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

С одной стороны, это мир механизмов, электричества ― технический прогресс **как таковой**. [Василий Корецкий, 2012]

Answer (score 1):

> ***У компьютера нет интеллекта как такового(,) и он называется аппаратом.***
>
> Word информирует, что пропущена запятая после как такового, т.е. перед
>   сочинительным союзом. Но найти основы в первой части предложение я не
>   могу.

Предложение сложносочинённое, запятая нужна.

Первое предложение здесь — безличное, основа в нём — слово ***нет***.

Разные лингвисты называют его в таких предложениях по-разному: предикативом, словом состояния, неизменяемой глагольной формой...